# Maneuvering at near light speed?

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity

Note, this might contain some minor spoilers for the Three Body Problem trilogy by Chixin Liu.

I have some kind of advanced star drive that allows for continuous minute acceleration. As I get closer to the speed of light, will it be take more energy to move orthogonally?

If I'm traveling at .5c there will be some minor relativistic effects, and it's my understanding it will take more energy to accelerate from .5c to .6c than it did from .4c to .5c. What about if I want to accelerate sideways to .1c? How much more energy would that require compared to accelerating to .1c while motionless?

Comment: Not enough content for an answer, but yes. There's no such thing as sideways 'speed,' only sideways velocity. Your speed would be the hypotenuse of a right triangle. Assuming you were moving at 0.5c and accelerated sideways by 0.1c, your new straight-line speed would be ~0.51c. So, you'd still use all the energy of actually accelerating, but the fun relativistic effects wouldn't be magnified very much.

Comment: You should also notice that when you get very close to c, the resistivity of the medium increases. At some point you would have to fire your drive constantly only just to maintain constant speed.